# Should HTML meta tags be avoided for Edge?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, meta

When one of our users tries to open our site in Edge, it instead opens in IE.  I understand there are some settings on their machine that may trigger this based on my research (group policies, intranet sites, compatibility modes, etc.)

In looking, I found this MS page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/emie-to-improve-compatibility

It says that "You must continue using IE11 if web apps use... `<meta>` tags".  I don't know if this means that any and all `<meta>` tags will trigger the "open it in IE" behavior, or if they're just recommending it.

I also thought things like `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` were highly important.  We also use a `<meta>` tag to indicate viewport dimensions/scaling/etc.

Should I avoid all `<meta>` tags?  Or just `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`?  I need to prevent the site from kicking over to IE from my end of things without relying on whatever the user has done to their settings (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if your website is intranet site, if so, since Edge has a group policy
​which opens all the intranet sites in IE, you could try the following steps:

1. Open Local Group Policy Editor.
2. Select "Administrative Templates".
3. Select "Windows Components".
4. Select "Microsoft Edge". Once you double click "Microsoft edge" you will see different settings & their current state.
5. Select "Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer 11" and then "Disabled" it.
6. Quit Edge & re-start (if required you might re-start your PC as well).

[image]

Comment: It's not an intranet site, though the server it's running on is in the same building as the machine that's having the issue.  It's possible it's considering it an "intranet" site if it's detecting it on the same network.